# How to restrict assets by Taxonomy in the Assets page

Tags: content-hub

Using `Content Hub v4.2`

I have created a `User Group` which has a policy where its user can select only a certain `Taxonomy (Access Group)` for an uploaded image.

But when this user browses the `Assets` page, the images from all other `Taxonomies` are displayed.
The Filters in the left side bar also displays the list of all `Taxonomies`.

Is it possible to restrict this user to view images only from the `Taxonomy` which was configured in the `User Group`.

[image]

This is what I have tried in the policy. Why isn't this working.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should define a new condition in the `User Group` for the `M.Asset`and `M.File`.
Then give the `Read` permission for the `Asset` tagged with only that particular `taxonomy` value. In that way, the user will see only the Assets for that taxonomy value.